# How do I pass props from a header component to another unrelated container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router, axios

I am using React-router-dom to switch between components as shown below.

```
<Router>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <NavigationBar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/concepts" component={ConceptBox} />
            <Route path="/products" component={ProductBox} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
```

Within by `<Header />` component I have a login section where users can log in. This connects to a MongoDB and returns a the response containing an array.

```
onSubmit = () => {
  if (this.state.email.trim() !== "" &&
  this.state.password.trim() !== "") {
    axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/login", { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
```

My express login route looks like:

```
router.route('/login')
.post(function(req, res){
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;

  Member.authenticate(email, password, function (error, user) {
        if (error || !user) {
          var err = new Error('Wrong email or password.');
          res.send(err);

        } else {
          console.log("I have your response now");
          return res.send(user)

        }
  });
```

I would like to use this array from  the response in the Home component.
I am confused whether I should be using reduxJS or a cookie to store this information and retrieve it in a different component? or is there a neat way of retrieving my

Answer (score 0):

You can store this array as a part of the main component's state. This is called [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

So, the component that contains the routing will have a function to receive the array as a param and update the state. This state will be passed to your `Home` component as a prop.

Your `console.log(response)` will be replaced by a call to this function.

Hope this helps! :)